# Problem with psaxes after update of package PSTricks

Tags: errors, pstricks, update

I have a problem with PSTricks and `\psaxes`. I have made an update of PSTricks package. The following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}
Essai de graphe

\newrgbcolor{qqwuqq}{0. 0.39215686274509803 0.}
\psset  {xunit=1.0cm,yunit=1.0cm,algebraic=true,dimen=middle,dotstyle=o,dotsize=5pt 0,linewidth=0.8pt,arrowsize=3pt 2,arrowinset=0.25}
\begin{pspicture*}(-3.,-5.)(4.,9.)
\psaxes[labelFontSize=\scriptstyle,xAxis=true,yAxis=true,Dx=1.,Dy=1.,ticksize=-2pt 0,subticks=2]{->}(0,0)(-3.,-5.)(4.,9.)
\psplot[linewidth=1.2pt,linecolor=qqwuqq,plotpoints=200]{-3.0}{10.0}{3.0*x+2.0}
\begin{scriptsize}
\rput[bl](-3.1,-7.88){\qqwuqq{$f$}}
\end{scriptsize}
\end{pspicture*}
\end{document}
```

generates the error:

```
Overfull \hbox (85.35823pt too wide) detected at line 11
 [] [] []
 []

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) detected at line 11
 [] [] []
 []
```

after the update. I have not have this problem before the update. What can I do?

Comment: Could you please be more specific and explain which version you are using? With my version it works.

Comment: That is only a warning which is not of interest here. For PostScript the axis has width 0, but not for LaTeX. However, ignore the warning. From which program do you get this exported pstricks code? It looks horrible!

Comment: I used the version number : 2.77: I have no warning with the version i used before. I have this pstricks code from Geogebra.

Comment: I have the same problem with this code :

Comment: \documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}
Essai de graphe

\psset{xunit=1.0cm,yunit=1.0cm}
\begin{pspicture*}(-3.,-5.)(4.,9.)
\psaxes{->}(0,0)(-3,-5)(4,9)
\psplot[linewidth=1.5pt,plotpoints=200]{-3}{4}{x 3 exp x -1 add 2 exp div -0.5 mul}
\end{pspicture*}
\end{document}

Comment: Again, it is a warning and not a real problem. It doesn't change the output! It _always_  happens with `\psaxes` and labels.

Comment: Thank for your answer ! But, why i don't have this problem (or this warning) before with a oldest version ?

Answer (score 1):

With up-to-date `pst-plot` it is no problem. By the way, the export of your
example from GeoGebra is buggy. Should be:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}
    Essai de graphe

\definecolor{qqwuqq}{rgb}{0. 0.392 0.}
\psset{algebraic,dimen=middle,dotstyle=o,dotsize=5pt 0,linewidth=0.8pt,
       arrowsize=3pt 2,arrowinset=0.25}
\begin{pspicture*}(-3.,-5.)(4.,9.)
\psaxes[labelFontSize=\scriptstyle,ticksize=-2pt 0,subticks=2]{->}(0,0)(-3.,-5.)(4.,9.)
    \psplot[linewidth=1.2pt,linecolor=qqwuqq,plotpoints=200]{-3.0}{10.0}{3.0*x+2.0}
    \rput[bl](-3.1,-7.88){\scriptsize\textcolor{qqwuqq}{$f$}}
\end{pspicture*}
\end{document}
```